# Unpack, modify and rebuild an Android App Bundles (.aab) file

Tags: disassembly, android

I would like to unpack an .aab file, decompile/recompile the classes.dex (baksmali/smali), edit the manifest and, finally, generate a new .aab file.

Basically, I am looking for an [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) for .aab

Comment: You can use bundletool to generate an APK from an want file and then decompile that APK

Comment: I'm aware, but it is not what I'm looking for!

Comment: I don't think that we will see such a tool soon because of two reasons: 1. Only the app developer her-/himself usually has an .aab file. You can't download it form anywhere, only generate if from an Android app you have the source code. 2. .aab files only make sense for uploading into Play Store. Therefore the use cases for modifying an .aab file are very limited. May be you should elaborate a bit more what you want to achieve and there is an easier way you have not noticed.

Comment: I am a developer of Obfuscapk, and I want to support .aab files as requested in this issue:
https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/Obfuscapk/issues/6

Comment: SimoneAonzo @Robert Did you guys get any solution to this?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/Obfuscapk/pull/121

Comment: @SimoneAonzo Since your question was solved as you mentioned, you can describe the solution as an answer in order to help the community in the future.